# Grab files changed by commit from GitLab API

Tags: gitlab-api

I am trying to use the GitLab API to grab all files changed by a particular commit, but I don't see a good way of doing it.

In other words, whats the equivalent of git show --name-only sha1 in the GitLab API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of is using the following API Call.

GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha/diff

(See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-the-diff-of-a-commit)

If you only need the changed files, you could of course only look at the file Paths (old_path, new_path) in the Response